# Union anti-meridian "multipolygons" after re-centering world map

Tags: r, maps, sp, ggplot2, rgeos

My goal is to create a world map (using ggplot2) with a Pacific perspective.

I have managed to re-center the map, by following this [solution](https://github.com/valentinitnelav/valentinitnelav.github.io/blob/master/gallery/Shift%20central%20(prime)%20meridian.R#L73). Code below:

```
    # world country layer
    sppolys <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sp")
    wgs84 <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")

    # =========================================================================
    # Split sPolygonsDF object by "split line"
    # =========================================================================
    # shift central/prime meridian towards west - positive values only
    shift <- 152 

    # create "split line" to split worldmap (split at Prime Meridian)
    split.line    <- sp::SpatialLines(list(Lines(list(Line(cbind(180 - shift, 
     c(-90, 90)))), ID="line")), 
     proj4string = wgs84)

    sppolys <- gBuffer(sppolys, byid=TRUE, width=0)

    # intersecting line with world polys 
    line.gInt     <- gIntersection(split.line, sppolys)

    # create a very thin polygon (buffer) out of the intersecting "split line"
    bf            <- gBuffer(line.gInt, byid=TRUE, width=0.000001)  

    # split world polys using intersecting thin polygon (buffer)
    sppolys.split <- gDifference(sppolys, bf, byid=TRUE)

    #==========================================================
    ## plot 
    #==========================================================

    countries <- data.table(map_data(as(sppolys.split, 
    "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")))

    # Shift coordinates to fall correctly on shifted map
    countries$long.shift <- countries$long + shift
    countries$long.shift <- ifelse(countries$long.shift > 180, 
    countries$long.shift - 360, countries$long.shift)

    # plot shifted map
    ggplot() + 
      geom_polygon(data=countries, 
        aes(x=long.shift, y=lat, group=group), 
        colour="black", fill="gray80", size = 0.25) +
      coord_equal()
```

Which results in the map below, providing a Pacific perspective, as desired.

[image: Pacific perspective, with polygons (Antarctica) split on anti-meridian]

However, polygons along the anti-meridian (now the map center) are still split. I suppose these could be unioned together somehow, which I tried to do with the following code (basically the inverse of the above splitting).

```
    # create SpatialLine where along anti-meridian
    old.split.line    <- sp::SpatialLines(list(Lines(list(Line(cbind(180, c(-90, 
    90)))), ID="line")), 
      proj4string = wgs84)

    # ID intersection btwn this line and polygons layer
    old.line.gInt     <- gIntersection(old.split.line, sppolys.split)

    # buffer it to ensure intersection
    old.bf            <- gBuffer(old.line.gInt, byid=TRUE, width=0.000001)  

    # union polygons which intersect the line
    sppolys.union <- gUnion(sppolys.split, old.bf)
```

The problem with this solution (as far as I can tell), is that the re-centering is done *after* converting to a data.table object, and therefore there is no actual intersection between the polygon parts. The only solution I can think if is to reconstruct a polygons object (`sp` or `sf`) after the shifting is done, but this is a huge hassle just to perform the unioning.

So in a nutshell, I'm looking for a way to shift/re-center the polygons THEN combine polygons along the old anti-meridian.

This can either be before or after converting to a data.table, whatever is most efficient. (Simple Features solutions are also welcome)